# Is there a good way to deal with dom selector in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm writing a Drag Component with React, there is a "handle" property to define the handle for drag with the 'propTypes' of `PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.node, PropTypes.string])`, means you can use a node or the string of node selector.

The question is, when i use selector string, i can only use `querySelectorAll` to get the node, then use `addEventListener` to bind event, i think, it's a bad way. The reason as follows:
When my component changed, the React will do some diff works, then update my DOM with a best way, that means, the node i get with selector may be changed to another node just for 'the best way'(For example: React just need to change the attribute of my node, it can convert my node to 'another' by this 'best way').

Comment: Could you  clarify your question? Why not provide some code toexplain your problem. Thank you

Comment: Your assumption is confusing you a lot. `addEventListener` works just as intended. You just need to make sure to `removeEventListener` when unmounting the component.